# Calling data from Wordpress custom meta box

Tags: php, wordpress

Alright, I have created a custom meta box on the post edit screens for my custom post type. What I'd like to be able to do with it is allow the user to input a link and then have a button where the post is displayed to take the user to the specified link. What hook would I use to call the meta boxes data?

Thanks!

JWinton

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the question, but :

1 - to display custom meta data you do not need a hook, but a function.

it is called is [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) (click the link to learn more.)

2 - If you want to create a link , usually what is done is to have 2 meta fields, One for the URL itself and one for the URL Display text ( or your button) .

Then you cann do , for example :

```
$my_URL = get_post_meta($post_id, $my_URL, true); ?>
$my_URL_mask = get_post_meta($post_id, $my_URL_mask, true); ?>
```

And then

```
 <a href="<? echo $my_URL; ?>" rel="whatever" title = "go to <?echo $my_URL;?>" alt="<?php echo $my_URL; ?>" /> <? echo $my_URL_mask ?> </a>
```

Now , if your custom fields values will be for example :

```
$my_URL = 'CLICK HERE';
$my_URL = 'http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta';
```

That will create you a link text link that will be like the one above .

If you do not want the url mask, and only the URL to display as text - then just use one value .

3 - If you want it to show in a BUTTON , that is a nother story, and it is CSS related - it will depend how you want your button to look, and in that case - you just put those values inside the markup.